# How to use if statement in foreach

Tags: php

I want to use if statement in  foreach

and want to get some result like this

```
 if ($nbb->rqn='change'){echo 'table-danger';} 
 if ($nbb->rqn='new'){echo 'table-success';} 
 and  ...
```

Here is my code :

```
<?php foreach ($product as $nbb): ?>
            <tr class="<?= if ($nbb->rqn='change'){echo 'table-danger';} ?>">

            <td ><?= $nbb->rqn; ?>
            .
            .
            .
            <td ><?= $nbb->cmk; ?>
        </tr>

        <?php endforeach ;?>
```

Comment: You need two use `==` or `===` if you want to compare variables. `=` is for assignments only.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php foreach ($product as $nbb): ?>



<tr class="<?php echo ($nbb->rqn =='change' ? 'table-danger' : '')  ?>">
        <td ><?= $nbb->rqn; ?>
        .
        .
        .
        <td ><?= $nbb->cmk; ?>
    </tr>

    <?php endforeach ;?>
```

Comment: Ternary syntax would be `echo $nbb->rqn =='change' ? 'table-danger' : ''`

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of if conditions that you need to compare why don't you user case statement?

```
switch (n) {
    case label1:
        code to be executed if n=label1;
        break;
    case label2:
        code to be executed if n=label2;
        break;
    case label3:
        code to be executed if n=label3;
        break;
    ...
    default:
        code to be executed if n is different from all labels;
}
```